# Tensor product vs ordinary product

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, complex-multiplication

I’m having a hard time understanding why can’t we see tensors as simple products on the base field.
See, if i select two subfields of a field $(\mathbb{F}; +; *)$ in such a way that they form a finite field extension $K=\mathbf{V}(\mathbb{F}^n)$, $Dim(\mathbf{V})=n$ for some natural $n$ over the original field, with $B=\{e_0;e_1;…;e_n\}$ being the base of the field extension $K$, then, since $\mathbf{V}$ is a subfield of the field itself, multiplication is automatically defined.

Let $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ be elements of $\mathbf{V}$. Then there is a trivial natural isomorphism:

$$φ:\mathbf{V}\otimes\mathbf{V}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$$

Given by the relation

$$φ(\vec{v}\otimes\vec{w})=a_v*b_w$$

Where $a_v$ and $b_w$ are the corresponding values of each vector in the main field. So, in this sense the “tensor product” between two (or more) vectors is just a multiplication. As an example. Take a function over $\mathbf{V}(\mathbb{F}^2)$;
$$f(x;y)=(xe_0+ye_1)^2$$
Evidently, if we have $f(a;b)+f(c;d)$, then
$$f(a;b)+f(c;d)
\\ =(ae_0)^2+2abe_0e_1+(be_1)^2+(ce_0)^2+2cde_0e_1+(de_1)^2
\\ =(a^2+c^2)e_0^2+2(ab+cd)e_0e_1+(b^2+d^2)e_1^2$$
so $f$ is (kinda) linear, hence, it acts like a map from $\mathbf{V}$ to $\mathbf{V}\otimes\mathbf{V}$… i could even define the composition of $f$ with the previous isomorphism $φ$ And claim
$(f\circ φ)(a;b)$ is a bilinear map!
I’m probably wrong about something, so a little clarification would be very helpful. Specifically, i would like to know if: is $(f\circ φ)$ a bilinear map? Can $f(x;y)$ be regarded as a tensor product of a vector by itself? Is there any situation in wich tensor products have exactly the same components as the expanded form of a multiplication?
Thanks for the help. Maybe i’m just mixing concepts.

Comment: "Since $V$ is the field itself"? even ???

Comment: The only time $V$ will be a field is if $n=1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, you’re right, i’ll edit soon, but there are many more situations in which $V$ is a field. It will be a field, for example, if it is a finite extension over another main field. That situation is important for this question.